# Where is this castle? I know it's somewhere in Ireland, but where?

Tags: ireland, identify-this, architecture, locate-this

[image]

Irish castle. I can find the picture everywhere but it never says where it's from.

Comment: Nice angle on the photo. It is taken in the only spot in Ireland where you can photograph Cashel Rock without having the town of Cashel in view. On second thought... It may have been doctored. I could have sworn some buildings from the town should be visible on the right-hand side, just sticking out over the edge of the hill.

Comment: Where are they taking the hobbits?

Answer (score 23):

This is the [Rock of Cashel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_of_Cashel). Located at Cashel, County Tipperary, Ireland.

This castle is also known as: Cashel of the Kings and St. Patrick's Rock.

Comment: To support the answer, it might be helpful if you find an attributed photograph of _Rock of Cashel_, perhaps from a different angle. Given the photographs on Wikipedia are usually released under a permissive license, that would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

It is the [Rock of Cashel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_of_Cashel).

The Wikipedia article says,

> The rock originated in the Devil’s Bit, a mountain 20 miles (30 km) north of Cashel, when St. Patrick banished Satan from a cave, resulting in the Rock’s landing in Cashel. Cashel is reputed to be the site of the conversion of the King of Munster by St Patrick in the 5th century.
>
> The Rock of Cashel was the traditional seat of the kings of Munster for several hundred years prior to the Norman invasion. In 1101, the King of Munster, Muirchertach Ua Briain, donated his fortress on the Rock to the Church. The picturesque complex has a character of its own and is one of the most remarkable collections of Celtic art and medieval architecture to be found anywhere in Europe. Few remnants of the early structures survive.The majority of buildings on the current site date from the 12th and 13th centuries.

Comment: I think you left out the "dubious, discuss" things on the page. Like the cave part....